# How do I collect the h1 headings of a number of web pages?

Tags: dom, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I would like to go through a couple of web pages

```
 theURLs := #('url1' 'url2' 'url3')
```

and get the content of the first h1 heading

```
theURLs collect: [ :anURL |  page := HTTPClient httpGetDocument: anURL.
                             page firstH1heading].
```

## Question

What do I need to put at the place of #firstH1heading ?

Answers for Squeak / Pharo / Cuis are welcome.

## Note

In Squeak

```
HTTPClient httpGetDocument: 'http://pharo.org/'
```

gives back a

```
MIMEDocument
```

So I would expect to do something like

```
theURLs collect: [ :anURL |  page := HTMLDocument on: 
                                     (HTTPClient httpGetDocument: anURL).
                             page firstH1heading].
```

But in Squeak 4.6 there is no HTMLDocument class though it seems there used to be one. (http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2249). The [Wiki](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2248) says that I should load a package **Network-HTML**. The SqueakMap catalog of Squeak 4.6 has a package 'XMLParser-HTML'. Can this be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pharo, you can use the [Soup package](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~PharoExtras/Soup). Install it via the Configuration Browser.

You retrieve a document from an URL with Zinc, and find the first `<h1>` tag with Soup like this:

```
|contents soup body|
contents := ZnClient new get: 'http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/small.html'.
soup := Soup fromString: contents.
body := soup body.
body findTag: 'h1'
```

Comment: Soup does not yet install in Pharo 5.0

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the configuration. You might need to refresh the catalog

```
Name: ConfigurationOfSoup-StephanEggermont.75
Author: StephanEggermont
Time: 14 December 2015, 1:39:52.307715 pm
UUID: 6c11fb83-5299-4852-9563-73ecc34992a0
Ancestors: ConfigurationOfSoup-FrancoisStephany.74

Adopted bug fix to stable 1.7.1 , added Pharo 5 versions
```